# The command 'meteor run android' show android window but nothing happend

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, sdk, angular-meteor

Am usiing:

- AngularMeteor
- Meteor
- Windows 8.1

Is the first time that I use androind and the command `$ meteor run androind`
Please Forgive me if my question is very novice.

When I put `$ meteor run androind` in my project, the aplication start up with normality in `localhost:3000` and I can see it in GoogleChrome or FireFox. All is with normality and the window androind start up, but not show anything.
and the console show `Starting app on Android Emulator          /` with the bar spinning infinity, and nothing happend.

Next the image:
[image]

After a very time waiting the sistem sendme this error

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed: C:\xx\xxxx\xxx\xxxx-app\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\cordova\run --emulator --emulator
   { [CordovaError: Failed to install apk to emulator: [  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk
   [  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk
   [  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
   [ 99%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk
   [100%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk
   pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk
   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]
   ]
   name: 'CordovaError',
   message: 'Failed to install apk to emulator: [  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  0%] /
data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  0%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  1%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  1%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  1%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  1%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  2%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  2%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  2%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  2%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  3%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  3%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  3%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  3%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  4%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  4%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  4%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  4%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  4%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  5%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  5%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  5%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  5%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  6%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  6%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  6%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  6%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  7%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  7%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  7%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  7%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  8%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  8%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  8%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  8%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  8%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  9%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  9%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  9%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  9%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 10%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 10%]
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 98%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 98%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 98%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 99%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 99%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 99%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 99%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[100%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n\tpkg:
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]\r\r\n',
   code: 0,
   context: undefined } 'CordovaError: Failed to install apk to emulator: [  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-a
rmv7-debug.apk\r\n[  0%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  0%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  1%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  1%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  1%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  1%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  2%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  2%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  2%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  2%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  3%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[  3%] /da
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
   ... more similar code 
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 98%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 98%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 98%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 98%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 99%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 99%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 99%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[ 99%] /da
ta/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n[100%]
   /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\n\tpkg: /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]\r\r\n\n    at
   C:\\a1\\xxxxx\\app\\xxxxx-app\\.meteor\\local\\cordova-build\\platforms\\android\\cordova\\lib\\emulator.js:401:36\n    at ChildProcess.exithandler (chil
d_process.js:204:7)\n    at emitTwo
   (events.js:87:13)\n    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)\n    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/
child_process.js:330:11)\n    at emitOne
   (events.js:77:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)\n    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:487:12)'
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (C:\tools\utils\processes.js:151:23)
   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
   => awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await
   (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_
modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:35:12)
   at CordovaProject.runCommands (C:\tools\cordova\project.js:715:22)
   at CordovaProject.run$ (C:\tools\cordova\project.js:261:10)
   at tryCatch (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runt
ime.js:63:40)
   at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib
\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:337:22)
   at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
   (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:96:21
)
   at tryCatch (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runt
ime.js:63:40)
   at invoke (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtim
e.js:139:20)
   at C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:184
:11
   at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regene
rator-runtime\runtime.js:183:16)
   at AsyncIterator.enqueue (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regenerator
-runtime\runtime.js:206:13)
   at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
   (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:96:21
)
   at Object.runtime.async (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\regenerator-
runtime\runtime.js:226:14)
   at C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\nod
e_modules\meteor-promise\fiber_pool.js:32:39

C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modu
les\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^
undefined
 => awaited here:
    at Function.Promise.await (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_7\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_m
odules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:35:12)
    at C:\tools\cordova\runner.js:98:17
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at CordovaRunner.startRunTargets (C:\tools\cordova\runner.js:97:37)
    at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:763:21)
    at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:876:28)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:403:12
```

Please, some ideas?
Thanks for your time

Comment: You Should choose Another OS Like Ubunthu or Mac Os

Answer (score 0):

I remember meteor doesn't support mobile building on windows.

More details, please view https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/running-on-mobile

Thanks,
Nicolas